# Get params from link in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS application with a rails API. I would like to enable my users to access to some templates thanks to links.

**The process would be**: click on the link, redirect to my Angular App, send a request to API accordingly to params and render my template.

My question is then, **how to send params in a link that my angular app would get?**

Comment: Any code to understand better?

Comment: Not really, I wonder if what I want to code is possible first :)

Comment: You need to pass them in the url. Following url may help you. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: @clement, If its possible using Javascript, its possible using Angular.

Comment: use ng-route it can prevent params, it is very easy to work with